# Why does this javascript refresh leak memory?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, memory-leaks

I have a dashboard on my TV and the page needs to refresh every second.

At the bottom of the page I have:

```
function startRefresh() {
    $.get('', function(data) {
        var newDoc = document.open("text/html", "replace");
        newDoc.write(data);
        newDoc.close();
    });
}
$(function() {
    setTimeout(startRefresh,1000);
});
```

This works great, except that each page load causes the memory usage to go up as reported by `chrome://memory-redirect/`.

Is there a way to fix this? I am not interested to create a separate page for a DIV and just reloading that part.

*FYI http header refresh and `document.location = document.location` both produced unusable flickering*

Comment: Maybe a bug. Have you tried it on other browsers?

Comment: I've tried your sample and the startRefresh function only runs once

Comment: My guess would be event dispatchers piling up handlers without dumping the window object along with document reset. In any case I'd avoid doc writes and use an iframe. the iframe will get you the true reload. It will have the same flicker to white problem, but because you're in an iframe you cn take advantage of css and solve it with https://css-tricks.com/prevent-white-flash-iframe/ You can also queue iframes offscreen for more interesting transitions in your TV app.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Chrome, you should use the "Timeline" to record the memory usage. Launch the timeline, then wait for the page to refresh a few times, and then stop the timeline and have a look at the results. If you see the line keeping increasing, that means your objects in memory (or the DOM nodes) are never released and garbage collected.

I have never used `document.open/write` myself so I do not know if that can cause issues with garbage collection, but I suspect it does.

If your detect clearly a memory lak using the Timeline, then open the "Profiles" tab and take a Heat snapshot before and after a page reload, then use "comparison" to see what have changed and how much bigger your memory impact is. If for instance your old compiled code (or obejct references) is still there, plus the new one, then it explains your leak.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [location.reload()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload)?

```
function startRefresh() {
    location.reload();
}
$(function() {
    setTimeout(startRefresh,1000);
});
```

EDIT: After re-reading the question, I realise you were not asking for an alternate method, but an explanation for the memory leak (which I don't have).

Comment: Solutions which don't present this problem are good too... but this one also suffers the white flicker problem.